# C# RabbitMQ Client thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, rabbitmq

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory {HostName = "localhost"};

using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        var user = new User 
                       {
                           Id = i
                       };

        Serializer.Serialize(stream, user);


        channel.BasicPublish("", "hello", null, stream.ToArray());

    }

}
```

I have the code above, and I'm curious about thread safety.

I am not sure, but I would imagine `ConnectionFactory` is thread safe. But is `IConnection` thread safe? Should I create a connection per request? Or rather a single persistent connection? And what about channel (`IModel`)?

Also, should I store the connection as ThreadLocal? Or should I create a connection per request?

Comment: see my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407760/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-pooling-connections-or-channels-in-rab/10501593#10501593

Answer (score 45, accepted):

IConnection is thread safe, IModel is not. Generally you should endeavour to keep a connection open for the lifetime of your application. This is especially true if you have consumers which need an open connection in order to receive messages. It's important to detect and recover from interrupted connections, either because of network or Broker failure. I'd recommend reading 'RabbitMQ in Action' by Videla and Williams, especially chapter 6 'Writing code that survives failure'.

Now for a shameless plug. I'm the author of [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com), a high-level .NET API for RabbitMQ. It does all the connection management for you and will automatically re-connect and rebuild all your subscribers if there's a network or broker outage. It also provides cluster and fail-over support out of the box. Give it a try.

Comment: "Extremely careful"? What kind of vague threat is that? EasyNetQ is a perfectly appropriate suggestion here. If people disagree, that's what the downvote button is for. It's unlikely the suggestion would've been given a second thought had he not also done the courtesy of disclaiming his authorship. I would be extremely careful about riding that high on your horse.

Comment: Good answer. It aligns with https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html

Comment: EasyNetQ is great! However I have been getting "Pipelining of requests forbidden" sometimes.