# MassTransit IBusControl instance lifecycle management in a web scenario

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit 3 to publish messages to RabbitMQ from a web server. My IBusControl instance is created manually but it's wrapped in a service. The service is injected using StrctureMap 2 and is request-scoped. IBusControl instance is disposed along with the service. I chose this approach mainly because I started noticing a lot of abandoned connections in the management console when I wasn't manually disposing of the IBusControl instance.

However, I am worried about the fact that it needs to open and close a connection to RabbitMQ on each request, especially in a high load environment (chat app) - that can't be "cheap." An alternative would be to make it a singleton, but I am wary of concurrency issues due to a large number of requests.

I am wondering whether there is a best practice in regards of lifecycle management for IBusControl instance in a web scenario. If not, are there any other alternatives that I missed?

**EDIT**: After doing more research and with the help of [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501593/39843) (and the [corresponding page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) in RabbitMQ docs), it appears that the best approach is to use a single connection for the lifetime of the app but create channels per thread, which would equate to a channel per web request.

Now the question becomes, when doing a Publish via MassTransit, does it use a new channel every time while maintaining the same connection?

Comment: Just keep the IBusControl alive for the life of the service. MassTransit will do everything else behind the scenes.