# Stop RabbitMQ consumer process current message

Tags: node.js, redis, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm writing a service on NodeJS that processes CPU-bound tasks. The main idea is pretty simple:

1. **Client** (browser) sends request
2. **Webserver** (NodeJS + ExpressJS) handles request: generates ID, adds a task to RabbitMQ with that ID and replies to client with that ID.
3. Also **webserver** adds the task to **Redis** server with ID as a key and `{status: active}` as a value
4. **Consumer processes a task** in about a minute **and updates redis** entry with the derived result.
5. **Client** uses this ID to check the status of the corresponding task.

**The question**: I wish consumer to stop processing the task in the step 4 if client has stopped asking server that the task is still running. How can I do that with RabbitMQ?

P.S.: I've tried to purge the queue but faced with some problems: the queue is not purged if the message was not acknowledged by consumer. As sad [here](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_purgeQueue), this will happen only after my CPU-bound task is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out my problem of purging consumer, but without using RabbitMQ, because didn't found any API for that.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40912169/3103181) on SO, I can check in another DB if the consumer should proceed or not. So I've decided to use **redis** also for this purpose: inside working thread I check an according entry in redis if the key has not expired yet.

Hope this would be helpful for somebody else.