# Are there any implications or pitfalls of accessing RabbitMQ IModel through a ThreadLocal?

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq, thread-local-storage

I have a created a class to facilitate simple text message transmission over a queue

```
public class TextQueueTransmitter
{
    private Func<IModel> channelProvider;
    private IBasicProperties props;
    private string queue;

    public TextQueueTransmitter(Func<IModel> channelProvider, string queue)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.channelProvider = channelProvider;
        
         //will be called once in a thread
        this.channelProvider().QueueDeclare(queue: queue,
                             durable: false,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: null);
        props = this.channelProvider().CreateBasicProperties();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        props.DeliveryMode = 1;
        
        //will be called multiple times not necessarily in the same thread
        channelProvider().BasicPublish(exchange: "",
            routingKey: queue,
            basicProperties: null,
            body: body);
    }
}
```

Initialization will be like

```
IConnection connection = ...
ThreadLocal channelThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<IModel>(connection.CreateModel);
TextQueueTransmitter transmitter = new TextQueueTransmitter(() => channelThreadLocal.Value, "queue name");
```

previously I was directly passing IModel to the transmitter but after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5681118/1303323) that IModel is not thread safe, I realized I had to rethink it if I wanted to make TextQueueTransmitter thread safe.

My question is are there any implications of just wrapping IModel in ThreadLocal? For example if SendMessage() is called in a thread other than the one that constructed the object, then `QueueDeclare` and `BasicPublish` will be called on different threads. Would that cause any problems?

#### Update: Resource disposal

As Samuel pointed out in his answer, there is the channel disposal issue that I have thought of but I forgot to write about. What I was planing to do, is call `Dispose()` of `ThreadLocal` on program's termination, *hoping* that this will call Dispose() of the underlying `IModel`s. Though I will have to verify since [ThreadLocal documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362195(v=vs.110).aspx) does not specify if it disposes the undelying objects (should they implement IDisposable).

This imposes the danger of "dangling" connections i.e. having connections for a specific thread no longer running. Though I don't consider it grave problem since all `TextQueueTransmitter` instances are intended to be long lived objects and I don't create threads excessively.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem I'd forsee is not disposing of the models and leaking resources. You need to have control over when they are created and dispose of them appropriately.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that very important thing that I forgot. :) I've updated my question so you might want to revisit and probably elaborate your thought.